# Why didn't the SpriteKit PhysicContactDelegate work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, sprite-kit

I am implementing a simple game for iOS. 
I am trying to use Sprite Kit for development.
However, I don't know why the detection of contact did not happen.
Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Here is the code that I cannot get the expected results with:

```
#import "TesttingScene.h"

@interface TesttingScene()<SKPhysicsContactDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) SKTexture *ballText;

@end

@implementation TesttingScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size{
    self = [super initWithSize:size];
    if (self) {
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

        SKSpriteNode *hitBoxx = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width/3, self.frame.size.height/3)];
        hitBoxx.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        hitBoxx.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
        hitBoxx.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:hitBoxx.frame.size];
        hitBoxx.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
        hitBoxx.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = abPlayerHitBoxCategory;
        hitBoxx.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = adsViewCategory;
        hitBoxx.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
        hitBoxx.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;

        self.ballText = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"FinalBossSkill1SS"];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    SKTexture *t1 = [SKTexture textureWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0.5, 1) inTexture:self.ballText];
    SKTexture *t2 = [SKTexture textureWithRect:CGRectMake(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) inTexture:self.ballText];
    SKSpriteNode *ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:t1];
    ball.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width, self.size.height/2);
    ball.name = @"FinalBossSkill1Ball";
    ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ball.size];
    ball.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    ball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = adsViewCategory;
    ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = abPlayerAttackBoxCategory | abPlayerHitBoxCategory;
    ball.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    ball.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    SKAction *moveTo = [SKAction moveToX:-ball.size.width duration:1.0];
    SKAction *flash = [SKAction animateWithTextures:@[t1,t2] timePerFrame:0.1];
    SKAction *moveBall = [SKAction repeatAction:flash count:moveTo.duration/flash.duration];
    SKAction *group = [SKAction group:@[moveTo, moveBall]];
    [self addChild:ball];
    [ball runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[group, [SKAction removeFromParent]]]];
}

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{
    NSLog(@"Contact");  // <~~~~this msg doesn't appear in console when the ball pass the hitboxx.
}
```

Comment: Contact of what and what? From what I can see there is only one object on the screen?

Comment: Remove the line which sets the collisionbitmask as 0 from both type of nodes

Comment: I want the SkpriteNote"Ball" contact the hitboxx, then the msg [NSLog(@"contact")] will be run.

Comment: re askashg:
I try it but it didn't work.

Comment: Leave the 3 bitmasks at their defaults for testing purposes. Also you should animate the ball using physics forces, not move actions, otherwise you lose most of the physics behaviors like bouncing off of other bodies, gravity.

Comment: I just want to detect when the ball touch the hitBoxx. As u can see, I have not simulate any physics like gravity or friction.
However, I don't know why the contact detection did't appear.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D is right. using SKActions will only cause problems in what you are trying to do. Try using [ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:]

Comment: For pure rectangle intersections you don't need to use physics, just use CGRectIntersectsRect and compare the two node's frames or accumulated frames.

Comment: How are you defining your constants adsViewCategory, abPlayerAttackBoxCategory, and abPlayerHitBoxCategory?  Also, do you want them to collide (physics to be applied to eachother) or just contact eachother (no physics applied)?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define bit mask category, right below your imports.

```
static const uint32_t abPlayerHitBoxCategory =  0x1 << 0;
static const uint32_t adsViewCategory =  0x1 << 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have already implemented these.
I found that if the moving velocity is too fast, the Physics delegate won't detect it. I think it is a limitation when I use SKAction for the movement.